# How to wget with pics on www.x.org/yy/index.php

Tags: linux, wget

I have an unusual case. I want to use wget to download all pictures on http://www.indyprojectseed.org/2011/index.php and all the other years. How can I do this, with a loop maybe?

I am currently doing

```
cd Downloads

wget -r -P /download/location -A jpg,jpeg,gif,png http://www.indyprojectseed.org/2011/index.php
```

However. I want to do with all the years. Idea?

Answer (score 1):

How about a bash loop, e.g.:

```
for year in {06..15}; do wget -r -P /download/location -A jpg,jpeg,gif,png http://www.indyprojectseed.org/20${year}/index.php; done
```

Comment: Those who downvote should explain why they do so, or it will look like an act of spite.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Thank you! This was my first answer, and I was getting a little discouraged.